# Shared Folder permission Denied on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, permissions, mount, samba, chmod

I have a strange problem with Ubuntu file permissions. I have a fresh ubuntu installed server and I've mounted a shared drive. sudo mount //Hostname:ifs/path/to/directory/file /mnt/my directory. The drive mounted successfully but whenever i try to go into any of the shared folder directory, it says "Permission Denied". If i use sudo su - "root" everything works perfectly. But my requirement is the standard user should be able to access the files same as root because we are running certain applications by the standard user which will eventually writes at the location "The mounted shared drive".

I've tried below things:- chown -v myuser:myuser /mnt/shared-drive
chmod -R 755 /mnt/shared-drive
chown -v myuser:myser /mnt/shared-drive

chmod gets stuck as the data is very huge at the shared drive which ubuntu will try to give full permissions to. The data is about 5-TB. Now even if i do chmod to the shared directory and and get the write permissions, when i create a directory and try to cd into it, it says "Permission denied"

If i copy one of the folders from the shared-drive to local, it still stays with the same error and i have to do chown -v myuser:myser /copied folder name then ti works and i can't keep doing it manually as this will be basically done by my application.

I've checked with the shared owner and he said, there are full permissions already assigned and should work without issues. I'm stuck here guys. Need your kind help.

Thank You!

Comment: Can you tell us what system the shared dir comes from? Is it linux, windows, qnap, synology?

Comment: Hello Thomas,
Thanks for the reply, it's a windows shared in my corporate environment with r/w access granted.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `sshfs` to share directories.

With the same user/pass on two machines, this is how I do it:

sshfs file sharing:

- 1) Install sshfs: `sudo apt_get install sshfs`
- 2) Mount dir: `sshfs <remote_host>:<dir> <local_dir>`
- 3) Umount dir: `fusermount -u <local_dir>`

You can set up sshfs so that you don't even need to enter a password when you use it.

Comment: Hello Bernt,Thansk alot for the prompt response.
I've tried as suggested, but the the below error

sudo sshfs /devicename:/ifs/file/to/path/shared_services /mnt/myfolder
read:connection reset by peer

Comment: I forgot of course! You need to install ssh server on your remote machine for this to work!  I find it easiest to use synaptic package manager to do this, look for openssh-server. Hope this helps a little

Comment: if i user below
sudo mount /devicename:/ifs/file/to/path/shared_services /mnt/myfolder it's mounted successfully. but when i try to cd into any directory, it says "permission denied"

If i change permission of any directory in the shared drive, it works after changing permission to 0755 or 777 but without that it won't.

Also FYI,
If i use root account, i have no problem but since root cannot be enabled for some reasons i need to use the account which was created at the time of installation example created a user "syed" at installation time and everything is under that user only now. :-)

Comment: But how can i have open-ssh server on a windows machine? It's a windows ifs share but same thing. I had requested the storage admin to give me an nfs share as well but the case is same with both shared servers with no luck.

Any permissions for the standard, sudo users to be granted? I have 50 server where i need to mount this but it's not working.

FYI,
Same shared drive is working perfectly if we mount it to any windows hosts it gives no errors. It's with only the Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Windows? Sorry, don't use it so I can't help you there.

Comment: No my mate,
I'm saying the mount works perfectly on windows if i mount it but not on Ubuntu 18.04.

It's an IBM NFS server from where the share is coming and i'm trying to mount it to my Ubuntu server that's it. Everything my storage team tried and they are able to mount it properly on RHEL/SUSE linux but getting this error on Ubuntu. :-(

Comment: Otherwise,
Is it possible to add the root permission to myuser as the mount drive is working fine for root account? any possibilities for this? Is there any special permissions required for myuser to be able to perform exactly as a root account?

Comment: You lost me there. I'm sorry I answered really, this is unfortunately too complicated for me to help you with ;(

Comment: I understand that, and really appreciate all your time for the responses.
I would just request you to kindly get me through any sort of cases and if someone who can help me in this regard would be highly appreciated mate.
Again, thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

> I've mounted a shared drive. sudo mount
>   //Hostname:ifs/path/to/directory/file /mnt/my directory.

Unless you have specified any other options that will mount the remote share with owner = root and write permissions only to root. CIFS is a virtual filesystem so chown and chmod will not work.

Take possession of the mounted share in the mount statement:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //hostname/sharename /mnt/my-directory -o uid=myuser
```

Comment: Hello Morbius,
Thanks for the response. So when i try that suggest, it says
"mount.cifs: bad UNC (devicename):/ifs/server/shared/parth

Comment: Your original question did confuse me a bit since you used //Hostname:ifs/path which looks like the syntax for NFS but you tagged the question as "samba". If this is a samba question you are using the wrong syntax. Use the one I suggested above.